# Why where condition is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try use left join for 2 tables. First table have primary key, second table do not have primary key

I use common sql syntax with simple commands.

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES(pk integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
CREATE TABLE CITIES(fk integer, Name text);

INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Lucy');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'Frank');

INSERT INTO CITIES VALUES(1,'Moscow');
INSERT INTO CITIES VALUES(3,'Saransk');
INSERT INTO CITIES VALUES(4,'Penza');
INSERT INTO CITIES VALUES(1,'Samara');

SELECT * FROM NAMES LEFT JOIN CITIES WHERE NAMES.pk = CITIES.fk
```

I hope see records with NULL. But i see only records which condition matched: https://rextester.com/FXMPF52805

Comment: Change `WHERE` to `ON`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Tnanks! It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct **Left Join** syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

---

so you should change `WHERE` to `ON`

```
 SELECT * FROM NAMES LEFT JOIN CITIES ON NAMES.pk = CITIES.fk
```

Answer (score 0):

when you choose to right joins as "Left JOIN, right Join, etc.."

you should write the query as below

> SELECT * FROM NAMES LEFT JOIN CITIES on NAMES.pk = CITIES.fk